# Ocaml : transform a pattern matching expression into if expression (if... then... else)

Tags: if-statement, recursion, pattern-matching, ocaml

I'm trying to write this pattern matching recursion expression

```
let rec drop_last l =
match l with
| [] -> []
| [_] -> [] 
| h::t -> h :: drop_last t ;;
```

as an *'if statement'* recursion expression.
I've started doing the following :

```
let rec drop_last2 l =
if l = [] then [] else 
if l = [_] then [] else
l = List.hd::List.tl then List.hd::drop_last2 (List.tl l);;
```

However, I'm getting a syntax error from the compiler. Could someone please tell me how should I modify this *if statement* into something correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeffrey said, `[_]` is a pattern not a value, you can't compare to it.

and in `l = List.hd::List.tl` first of all it's incorrect, `List.hd` is a function that takes a list and returns it's it's head, `List.tl` is also a function that takes a list but this one returns it's tail, and the constructor `_::_` takes a value and a list of values of the same type. So you should really check the documentation (https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) for more information on how to use functions and costructors.

to go from this:

```ml
let rec drop_last l =
match l with
| [] -> []
| [_] -> [] 
| h::t -> h :: drop_last t ;;
```

to an if-statement, you can do it this way:

```ml
let rec drop_last l =
  if List.length l <= 1 
  then []
  else List.hd l :: drop_last (List.tl l) ;;
```

That is because the pattern `[]` checks if the list is empty, so it can be replaced by `List.length l = 0` and `[_]` checks if the list has one element, so it can be replaced by `List.length l = 1` and since in both those cases you return `[]`, you can join them with `List.length l <= 1` and `List.hd` requires an argument that list a list, so it needs to be applied to `l` to give you the head, then appended to the recursive call with the tail to create a new list to be returned.

Comment: Suggestion: use `List.compare_length_with l 1 <> 1` rather than `List.length l <= 1`. The latter needs to compute the entire length of the function. The former stops at determining if the list length is longer than 1 or not.

Answer (score 0):

The construct `[_]` is a pattern, not a value. So you can't use `=` to compare it to a value as you are trying to do.

The thing to do, I believe, is to concentrate on thinking about the length of the list. The pattern `[]` matches when the length is 0 and the pattern `[_]` matches when the length is 1. You can use these facts in your `if` statements.